# How to calculate this integral over cosx?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'd like to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_{-1}^1\exp\left(\frac{2r\xi \cos\theta}{4\kappa t}\right)\,\mathrm{d}(\cos\theta)$$

I don't know how I should interpret the $d\cos\theta$ during integration.

I cannot find materials on this online, but I suspect I'm not formulating it properly, so I'd be happy to even just get suggestions where/how to look for it.

Appreciate it!

Comment: You can treat $\cos\theta$ as a variable or write $d(\cos\theta)=-\sin(\theta)d\theta$

Comment: It is a notation that appears in integration by parts. It can be thought of as standing for: "$\frac{\mathrm{d}(\cos\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\cdot\mathrm{d}\theta$", but also as for a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. If you substitute $t=\cos\theta$ you will be better placed

Comment: No, do not use the letter $t$ when it already appears in the problem. But you'll end up with a simple integration $\int\exp(cu)\,du$ ...

Comment: Taking $c=\cos\theta$, it's literally just $\int_{-1}^1\exp\left(\frac{r\xi c}{2\kappa t}\right)\,\mathrm{d}c$. At least, I _think_ the original integral limits are values for $c$ rather than $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you all! It was helpful